# Remove the related record then count

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table:

| ID | Target | Belong | FlowType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

I want to get the count of the each `Target` To `belong` with `FlowType = 1` but `FlowType = 3` means return and then the record exists do not count.

for example the records I post before

the count should be 1 becuase although there was two Target 1 to Belong 3 but there was 1 returned.

if there is no `ID = 3` then the `count` should be 0.

If the is another record

| ID | Target | Belong | FlowType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 6 | 1 |

then `count` should be two.
since there is two `FlowType = 1` and only 1 `FlowType = 3`

But I do not want to get the all `count` but want to get the count for Each `Belong`
I will get the all `Belongs` of `Belong = 3` and `belong =1` and then get the count of each of them.

means I want to group by the `Belong` and then get the count of each `Belong`

```
select
(select count(case when....?) from MyTable s1 where s1.Belong = s.Belong),
s.Belong

From MyTable s
Group By Belong
```

I want the result of:

| Belong | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

Comment: Your last statement is rather unclear. Please consider edit it with some example and include the expected result for each scenario

Comment: I can't get it still. After the second table, do you mean you get three flow type = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get the count of FlowType-1 rows minus the the count of FlowType-3 rows:

```
select
  count(case when flowtype = 1 then 1 end) -
  count(case when flowtype = 3 then 1 end) as diff
from mytable;
```

Another way to write this:

```
select
  sum(case when flowtype = 1 then  1 
           when flowtype = 3 then -1
      end) as diff
from mytable;
```

Comment: No I think it is not right becuase maybe `flowtype = 3` but target and belong will not same. forexample  `target = 10 belong = 11` 10 and 11 may not in the table

Comment: No I think it is not right becuase maybe `flowtype = 3` but target and belong will not same. forexample  `target = 10 belong = 11` 10 and 11 may not in the table

Comment: flowtype = 3 means return. So, for every flowtype-3 row there must be a flowtype-1 row for the same target/belong pair (reversed), because otherwise the return would have no original row it references. Is this assumption incorrect? Then get into more detail. What flowtypes exist? And how to tell which rows belong together?

Comment: Are you saying that there can be a flowtype-3 row for target = 10 and belong = 11, but no flowtype-1 row for target = 11 and belong = 10, and for that reason you would not count the   flowtype-3 row? In your example you count the flowtype-3 row #2, because it matches the flowtype-1 row #1. But how do you know then that it refers to row #1? Can't it be that the row belongs to a row that is not in the table and row #1 was never returned? So, if it is possible for a flowtype-3 row to have no corresponding flowtype-1 row, how can you tell if and which flowtype-1 row a flowtype-3 row references?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTable;

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (
    ID int,
    Target int,
    Belong int,
    FlowType int
);

INSERT INTO #tempTable (ID, Target, Belong, FlowType)
VALUES (1, 1, 3, 1),
       (2, 3, 1, 3),
       (3, 1, 3, 1);

SELECT DS_FT1.Target
      ,DS_FT1.Belong
      ,DS_FT1.records - ISNULL(DS_FT3.records, 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT Target
          ,Belong
          ,COUNT(*) AS records   
    FROM #tempTable 
    WHERE FlowType = 1
    GROUP BY Target
            ,Belong
) DS_FT1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Belong AS Target
          ,Target AS Belong
          ,COUNT(*) AS records  
    FROM #tempTable 
    WHERE FlowType = 3
    GROUP BY Belong
            ,Target
) DS_FT3
    ON DS_FT1.[Target] = DS_FT3.[Target]
    AND DS_FT1.[Belong] = DS_FT3.[Belong]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all rows with `FlowType = 1` as rows with positive items and all rows with `FlowType = 3` as rows with negative items and swapped `Target` and `Belong`.

Then just sum up all items and negative items would cancel out some positive items.

If you have more rows with `FlowType = 3` than rows with `FlowType = 1`, then the final count will be negative.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        +1 AS Item
        ,Target AS V1
        ,Belong AS V2
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE
        FlowType = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        -1 AS Item
        ,Belong AS V1
        ,Target AS V2
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE
        FlowType = 3
)
SELECT
    V1 AS Target
    ,V2 AS Belong
    ,SUM(Item) AS FinalCount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY
    V1
    ,V2
;
```

Here is one more variant that scans the table only once. Idea is the same - have positive items when `FlowType = 1` and negative items with swapped columns when `FlowType is not 1`. This method assumes that there are only two values for `FlowType`. If you have more than `1` and `3` values, then you need to add a filter `WHERE FlowType IN (1,3)`.

```
SELECT
    V1
    ,V2
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN FlowType = 1 THEN +1 ELSE -1 END) AS FinalCount
FROM
    MyTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN FlowType = 1 THEN Target ELSE Belong END AS V1
            ,CASE WHEN FlowType = 1 THEN Belong ELSE Target END AS V2
    ) AS A
WHERE FlowType IN (1,3) -- Add this filter if there can be other values for FlowType 
GROUP BY
    V1, V2
;
```

I put expressions for `V1` and `V2` into `CROSS APPLY` to make the query more readable. Without this trick you'd have to repeat these lengthy expressions in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, while now you can just reference `V1` and `V2`.